# Supporting Drop Caps in Text Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-text, textkit

I’m building an iOS reader app where I need to be able to highlight selections of text and optionally link notes with highlights.   I’ve begun by using Text Kit (`UITextView`, `NSAttributedString`).  I am targeting iOS 7, 8, and 9.

My **problem** is that I need to be able to support Drop Caps on certain paragraphs in the content.  This means the first letter of a paragraph is the height of 2 lines of text and the first 2 lines of text appear beside it, then the remaining lines wrap under.  My content has many drop cap characters on various paragraphs throughout.

[image: drop cap example] *Example showing 4-line drop cap.*

### Text Kit: Exclusion Paths

My initial assumption was that I would use Text Kit exclusion paths so that paragraph would wrap around it.  But I can’t figure out a way to determine the exact placement of the exclusion paths and I wasn’t sure if these would float along as my content scrolls.  With this approach, I would also have to manually handle text selection of the Drop Cap characters, which I’d like to avoid.

### Text Kit: NSTextAttachments

I was hopeful that I could use inline Text Attachments (`NSTextAttachment`), but I can’t determine a way to have 2 lines wrap beside it.

### Core Text

I found a couple older (pre-TextKit) examples of Drop Cap implementations using Core Text, however, every one showed only the first character of the content as a Drop Cap and not multiple paragraphs throughout the content as I need.  I was hoping to avoid Core Text also since I’d rather not handle text selection manually.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469897
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14639864
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9272955

### Current Hope/Question

`NSTextAttachment` feels like the simplest approach.  Is there a way to wrap 2 lines of text beside it?

Fallback... I’m beginning to wonder if I should switch to `WKWebView` and drop iOS 7 -- since HTML supports drop caps and `WKWebView` provides more performance than `UIWebView`.

Comment: Any luck? Did you find a good solution? I'm struggling with the same problem.

Comment: @Tieme Due to the timeframe of my app, I ended up going with WKWebView and rendering my content as HTML.  I used lots of JavaScript to handle highlighting of the text where the user took notes.

Comment: Check. We can't leverage WebViews because we have to render native content in between text components.. I'm going to investigate https://stackoverflow.com/a/14639864/1218605. Thanks!